# Github API for code comments

Tags: git, api, rest, github

I haven't been able to determine if GitHub's API provides access to user comments. I'd like to be able to grab the comments made on commits as well as the *per-line* comments via a RESTful API. I'd also like to be able to add comments and in-line comments via an API.

Is there something I've missed in the API, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an email from GitHub support indicating they don't currently support this feature:

> We don't support comments in the API at this time.

Answer (score 7):

This has now been enabled as of v3, http://develop.github.com/p/commits.html

Comment: The URL describing this functionality is here: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/